# x-access-token not intercepting in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, interceptor, postman

When i use chrome extension called POSTMAN to call an api

```
api.get('/me', function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.decoded);
});

return api;
```

Using x-access-token as a header with a valid token value, i get a valid respond.

When using interceptor i copied from online tutorial i get this error message:

> http://localhost:3000/api/me 403 (Forbidden)

**My API**

```
module.exports = function(app, express) {
api.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var token = req.body.token || req.param('token') || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    if (token) {
        jsonwebtoken.verify(token, secretKey, function(err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(403).send({ sucess: false, message: "Failed to authenticate"});
            } else {
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.status(403).send({ success: false, message: "No Token Provided"});
    }
});

api.get('/me', function(req, res) {
        res.json(req.decoded);
    });

    return api; 
}
```

**My Authentication Service**

```
.factory('Auth', function($http, $q, AuthToken) {

    var authFactory = {};
    authFactory.getUser = function() {
        if(AuthToken.getToken())

         ///Here it breaks here

            return $http.get('/api/me');
        else
            return $q.reject({ message: "User has no fucking token"});
    }
    return authFactory;
})
.factory('AuthToken', function($window) {
var authTokenFactory = {};

authTokenFactory.getToken = function() {
    return $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
}

authTokenFactory.setToken = function(token) {
    if (token)
        $window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    else
        $window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
}

return authTokenFactory;

})
.factory('AuthInterceptor', function($q, $location, AuthToken) {
var interceptorFactory = {};

 interceptorFactory.request = function(config) {
    var token = AuthToken.getToken();

    if(token) {
        config.header['x-access-token'] = token;
    }

    return config;
 };

 interceptorFactory.responeError = function(response) {
    if (response.status == 403)
        $location.path('/login');
    return $q.reject(response);
 }
 return interceptorFactory; })



.factory('Auth', function($http, $q, AuthToken) {

var authFactory = {};

authFactory.getUser = function() {
    if(AuthToken.getToken())
        return $http.get('/api/me');
    else
        return $q.reject({ message: "User has no fucking token"});
}
return authFactory; })
```

Comment: What is `AuthToken.getToken()` doing

Comment: Ohh my bad... check the code again i just re-edit the post. Anyway AuthToken.getToken() works fine, as i can see the token being set using POSTMAN

Comment: So where is it hitting this 403, you have it in 4 different spots. Put some alerts/console logs everywhere and see what the actual response is, to try and sniff out why. Try Fiddler even

Comment: Hey mcp, I just added more code to the post. After i login has been sucessful, i want to get user details using authFactory.getUser(), but it seems to give me an 403 error when trying to retrieve the user details.

Comment: I had to use this for it to work. config.headers['X-AUTH-TOKEN']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure the interceptor is in effect, by adding it to $httpProvider. The following code does this, inside of the config for the app:

```
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
});
```

As a heads up, you have a misspelling:

```
interceptorFactory.responeError -> interceptorFactory.responseError
```

Edit:

Also, having interceptors helps when you want the same behaviour for multiple requests without having to alter each request. For this use case, perhaps it is simpler not using an interceptor, but rather adding the header in manually for the one request:

```
return $http.get('/api/me', { headers: {'x-access-token': AuthToken.getToken()} });
```

Comment: Beat me to it :) Yes you need to be doing interceptors in your `.config()`

Comment: I am sorry but i am pretty new to MVC and angular, but inside my app.js i only have the following line:
angular.module('MyApp', ['appRoutes','mainCtrl','authService']);
I tried putting that code at the bottom of that line and it gives me a syntax error

Comment: What's the syntax error you're getting? Try angular.module('yourAppName').config(...)

Comment: Ok i put that code in the authentication service and now i am getting Cannot set property 'x-access-token' of undefined
    at interceptorFactory.request

Comment: I think there may be another spelling mistake: `config.header['x-access-token'] = token;` change `header` to `headers`

Comment: After all i didnt even need this code: 
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
});

I just spell header wrong....... dam man, been at it for hours

Comment: That's the way it goes :)